# Grails custom tag doesn't work with <g:link params>

Tags: grails, gsp, taglib

I have in my GSP page a `<g:link action="test" params='["present": "yes"]'` tag which, when clicked, sends me to a URL ending with `/test?present=yes`.

If I define this custom tag lib:

```
class HelperTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = 'html'

    static returnObjectForTags = ['passthrough']

    def passthrough = { Map attrs, Object body ->
        return attrs
    }
}
```

and add it to the tag, `<g:link action="test" params='${passthrough(["present": "yes"])}'`, suddenly my URL ends with `/test`, completely losing the params.

Why does this happen and how can I work around it?

Comment: Have you tried using as `params="${passthrough(['present': 'yes'])}"`. Mark the use of `"` and `'`.

Comment: why don't you allow your taglib to render that link for you. Try this </g:passthrough> in gsp and in taglib def passthrough = { attrs, body ->
        out << g.link(controller: 'foo', action: 'test', params: [present: 'yes']) 
    }. Haven't tried it but waiting to hear from you.

Comment: @swapnilsawant That worked well, thanks.  I still don't understand why my original code is broken, but this is a good workaround (probably better than what I was trying to do anyway).

Comment: @Kiwi  Good to hear that it worked for you, I have done rendering links from taglib before, but dont know whether its a best practice or not. I will put it as an answer to accept so help seekers can refer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow your taglib to render that link for you. Try this `</g:passthrough>` in gsp and in taglib

```
def passthrough = { attrs, body -> out << g.link(controller: 'foo', action: 'test', params: [present: 'yes']) }
```

Answer (score 0):

i can see you miss **g.taglibname** in your call to taglib, it should be like this

`<g:link action="index" params="${g.doSomething(present:true)}">Ir</g:link>`

i did it my self and its work fine

but if what you want is to intercept some params, and then procesit before complete the request maybe a better solution is using beforeInpreceptor feature or some filter.

more info about interceptors here http://www.grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/beforeInterceptor.html

hope it can help

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, but I appreciate the effort; thanks.  It's good to know about interceptors too.

Comment: its working for me, just to recap use g.tagName insted of just tagName and remove does [] when try to pass atributes if you need more attrs just split them with ,